# How do I access a Formik context's validationSchema?

Tags: formik

tl;dr The result of `useFormikContext()` doesn't include its `validationSchema`.  Based on its [TypeScript types](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/b9cc2536a1edb9f2d69c4cd20ecf4fa0f8059ade/packages/formik/src/types.tsx#L255), it exists on the object as an optional property, but for some reason, I don't know how to make it appear.

I have a generic component that takes in a `fieldName` prop.  I think use `useField(fieldName)` to retrieve the data.  Now I want to check if there's a `validationSchema`, and if there is, do something with it (e.g. determine if the field has a `max()` test).

```ts
const MyComp = ({ fieldName, maxLength, ...props }) => {
  // for some reason, validationSchema is always undefined
  const { validationSchema } = useFormikContext();

  if (maxLength == null && validationSchema) {
    // never gets here because validationSchema is always undefined
    maxLength = Yup.reach(validationSchema, fieldName)
      ?.tests.find(t => t.OPTIONS.name === 'max')
      ?.OPTIONS.params.max;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      The maxLength of <code>{fieldName}</code> length is{' '}
      <code>{maxLength ?? 'undefined'}</code>.
      {'\n'}
      Its <code>validationSchema</code> via{' '}
      <code>useFormikContext()</code> is{' '}
      <b>{
        validationSchema === null ? 'null' : 
        validationSchema ? 'definied' : 
        'not defined'
      }</b>.
    </div>
  );
};

const schema = Yup.object({
  withoutMaxLength: Yup.string(),
  withMaxLength: Yup.string().max(10),
  withMaxLengthProp: Yup.string()
});

const initialValues = {
  withoutMaxLength: "",
  withMaxLength: "",
  withMaxLengthProp: ""
};

const App = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSumbit={() => {}}
    validationSchema={schema}
  >
    <Form>
      <MyComp fieldName="withoutMaxLength" />
      <MyComp fieldName="withMaxLength" />
      <MyComp fieldName="withMaxLengthProp" maxLength={10} />
    </Form>
  </Formik>
);
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-w2gz7b?file=/index.js)

**Result**
[image: Result of code]

As you can see above, `useFormikContext().validationSchema` is always `undefined` even though it *is* set as a property of `<Formik />`.  Any idea why or what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a [known bug](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/3335) in formik, and has been [fixed in v3](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/pull/3231).  My best option appears to be `yarn patch`, or it would be if formik weren't an external for my library.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - did you end up doing a patch, or trying to update to the @next version?

Answer (score 2):

### Workaround

As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is a known bug that apparently has been fixed in v3. However, the latest stable version is still considered 2.2.9. So if you don't want to take any chances with the unstable version, you can use a workaround instead.

[Here's a working example](https://playcode.io/1452949).

The gist is to create a wrapper component that contains a single property -- `validationSchema` -- and pass that down using [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) along with a custom hook to get that context. That way you can get the `validationSchema` just like you were ***supposed*** to be able to with the `useFormikContext`. You would use it by simply wrapping your `<Formik>` component with your custom component (I'll prepend the custom stuff with a "Rad" prefix - so in this case `<RadFormik>`:

```
// Your form

<RadFormik validationSchema={validationSchema}>
  <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', rowGap: 2, mt: 4, mb: 8 }}>
        <RadTextField fullWidth name="name" label="Name" />
        <RadTextField fullWidth name="email" label="Email" />
      </Box>
    </Form>
  </Formik>
</RadFormik>
```

We're creating the context and hook in our `RadFormik` component:

```
// RadFormik.tsx

import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

interface RadFormikProps {
  validationSchema: Yup.ObjectSchema<any>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface RadFormikContextType {
  validationSchema: Yup.ObjectSchema<any>;
}

const RadFormikContext = createContext<RadFormikContextType>({
  validationSchema: Yup.object(),
});

export const useRadFormikContext = () => useContext(RadFormikContext);

export const RadFormik = ({ validationSchema, children }: RadFormikProps) => {
  const contextValue = {
    validationSchema,
  };

  return <RadFormikContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</RadFormikContext.Provider>;
};
```

And then finally, we can consume that context in a custom text input using our custom `useRadFormikContext` hook. In this example, I'm creating a custom textfield based on [MUI's TextField component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/):

```
// RadTextField.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useRadFormikContext } from './RadFormik';

type RadTextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
  name: string;
  label: string;
};

export const RadTextField: React.FC<RadTextFieldProps> = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);
  const { validationSchema } = useRadFormikContext();
  console.log('validationSchema', validationSchema);


  const isFieldRequired = () => {
    try {
      const fieldSchema = validationSchema?.fields[name];
      return !!fieldSchema?.exclusiveTests?.required;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      {...field}
      label={props.label}
      required={isFieldRequired()}
      error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
      helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
    />
  );
};
```